# Groupby and random select without replacement by a column

Tags: python, sql, pandas, aggregate-functions

Here is the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Name":["AAA", "ABC", "CCC", "XYZ", "DEF", "YYH"],
"Group_id":[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "tax_id": [100, 50, 200, 200, 300, 300]})
df.head()
```

I want to group by `Group_id` and select at most n random rows for each group, where `tax_id` is unique:

Here is my solution which is not complete. It will select at most 3 samples for every group but `tax_id` is not unique.

```
for n= 3

df.groupby("Group_id").apply(lambda x: x if len(x) < n else x.sample(n, random_state=123))
```

[image]

Suggestion to finish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

We can drop duplications before:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(["tax_id", "Group_id"])
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

df.groupby("Group_id").apply(lambda x: x if len(x) else x.sample(3, random_state=123))
```

Comment: Suppose you could also (depending how large it is - just randomise the entire DF first) - and do something like: `df.sample(len(df)).drop_duplicates(['Group_id', 'tax_id']).groupby('Group_id').head(3)`

Answer (score 0):

If your sampling strategy is based on the distribution of the most common combinations of group_id and tax_id, by dropping the duplicates you lose a piece of information.
If you want to preserve that distribution here is one solution where n is a parameter that determines the number of samplings:

```
sliced_data = data.copy()
n = 3
samples = pd.DataFrame()
for n in range(n):
    _grouped = sliced_data.groupby("Group_id")
    sample = _grouped.sample(1,random_state =13)
    for i, s in sample.iterrows():
        x = sliced_data.loc[(sliced_data.Group_id == s[1])&(sliced_data.tax_id== s[2])]
        sliced_data = sliced_data.drop(x.index)
    samples = pd.concat([samples,sample])
```